how can i get the patch description, name, release data and image eventually of a specfic battlenet game
i want to get the latest patch description, name, release data and image eventually of a specfic battlenet game is that possible?

this is a website? why exactly do you think there would be json?

i dont im just asking if there is

Here is an example how you can use their REST Json API to get all articles:
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

json_url = "https://news.blizzard.com/en-us/blog/list?pageNum={page_num}&pageSize=30&community=diablo4"

page_num = 1
while True:
    data = requests.get(json_url.format(page_num=page_num)).json()

    soup = BeautifulSoup(data["html"], "html.parser")
    for article in soup.select("article"):
        print(article.a.text)
        # parse other data
        # ...

    if data["pageNum"] * data["pageSize"] > data["totalCount"]:
        break

    page_num += 1

Prints:
...

Diablo IV Quarterly Update—December 2020
Diablo IV Quarterly Update—September 2020
Diablo IV Quarterly Update—June 2020
Diablo IV Quarterly Update—February 2020
System Design in Diablo IV (Part II)
System Design in Diablo IV (Part I)
A Letter from our Game Director – BlizzCon 2019
Diablo IV Feature Overview
Diablo IV Unveiled


is it possible to get the description of the latest patch, of a specific game the name of the latest patch, when the latest patch was released and maybe the image or something like that

@ClashersLab Latest patch notes I think are in this URL https://news.blizzard.com/en-us/diablo4/23964909/diablo-iv-patch-notes
